# How to grab last 12 12 months from cygwin "date" INCLUDING FEBRUARY

Tags: date, cygwin

I want to make directories for the last 12 months, starting whenever I run my script.  I've got this code, which is %90 good:

```
for i in {1..12}; do
    mkdir "$(date -d "$i months ago" +%Y-%m)-01"
```

The problem is that instead of making a `2011-02-01` directory it tries to make 2 `2011-03-01` directories.  My guess is that because today is the 29th, it's going back a month at a time and interprets February 29th as March 1st.  Any way to make sure I get a Feb directory too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "$(date -d "$(date +%Y-%m-15) -$i months" +%Y-%m)-01"
```

This means that it tries going back from the 15th of each month instead of the current day.

Comment: I think you want `date +%Y-%m-15` not `date -d +%Y-%m-15`